# Git Repository for Multiple OSes

Tags: git

I am writing a program that will directly call the Windows/Linux API for graphics. All of the non-graphics code is the same. I would like to be able to push non-graphics code to both branches, and pull just the code for one OS. What is the proper way to organize the repository?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) and use a submodules for your platform specific code.